# How to import multiple class with "import as" on a single line

Tags: python

I want to import something like this

```
from x import t as b
from x import u as c
```

Is there a way to use a single `from x` to achieve the same effect

Comment: Duplicate, but don't do that. It makes it difficult to read.

Comment: Check out: [PEP 8 -- imports](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following works:

```
from x import t as b, u as c
```